Setting same image background for all angular components?
Is there a way to have same image that would be used as a background for all components? Putting the background in src css does technically apply it to every component, but issue is if the component is the size of the page, the background is back to white, or if it is smaller - a bit of the background peaks out under the component. After mainly working with just raw html and using a html template for all pages, this seems very unintuitive.
I have tried manually cheating my way by setting the background of components to transparent (doesn't work), but surely there has to be an easier way to do this? Using src css in components if it worked would mess up the pattern of the background image too. Tried something from a similar question:
@Component({
  selector: 'app-showcase',
  templateUrl: './showcase.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./showcase.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

Encapsulation does not work either

Doesn't background-size help? It's much better to post rendered HTML/CSS snippet that can be easily debugged and not copy code from templates https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do
